# how to unload a module and all its data in pytorch c++ api?

Tags: c++, pytorch, artificial-intelligence

I am using c++ api of Pytorch in windows for loading modules. I have created dll for loading model and doing some stuff in my main program.  My issue is that How to unload module from cuda memory?

I am Loading Module Like this

```
    m_Module = torch::jit::load(modulePath, m_Device);
    m_Module.to(m_Device);
```

Now please can anyone tell me How to unload the module and free the cuda memory?